# Generating random weighted adjacency matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, sparse-matrix, adjacency-matrix

I would like to create a random adjacency matrix in MATLAB such that the total sum of weight is equal to the number of edges. Finally find the Laplacian matrix using

```
L = diag(sum(A)) - A
```

and then graph it. Is there any way to do so?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What part of it are you struggling with exactly? The creation of the adjacency matrix, calculation of the Laplacian matrix or the graphing?

Comment: directed graph? undirected graph? degree of nodes? num of edges?

Comment: thanks for the responses.

@ Arik, it is somehow leading me to write a semester project. I do not know actually how to create a random weighted adjacency matrix such that total weights are equal to number of edges in the graph. Then may some of them have weights greater that 1 others smaller. The rest would be easy finding Laplacian Matrix, graph, ... . 
@Shai, let' assume it is undirected and we can find the degree nodes by knowing how many nonzero entries are in a row of the Adjacency matrix. the main problem for me is what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An adjacency matrix for an undirected graph is simply a square symmetric matrix.
If you have no constraints on the degree of the nodes only on the weights than I would suggest something like

```
n ; % number of nodes in the graph
density = 1e-3; % a rough estimate of the amount of edges       
A = sprand( n, n, density ); % generate adjacency matrix at random
% normalize weights to sum to num of edges
A = tril( A, -1 );    
A = spfun( @(x) x./nnz(A), A );    
% make it symmetric (for undirected graph)
A = A + A.';
```

I have used in this code:

- [`sprand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprand.html) to generate random sparse matrix.
- [`spfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spfun.html) to help normalize the edge weights.
- [`tril`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html) to extract only half the matrix.